# How to access google endpoints 2 with iOS

Tags: ios, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I had a working app on both iOS and android.

I have since migrated my endpoints to version 2 using android studio and my android app is still working.

However my iOS one is no longer working but I can not find any documentation explaining how to access google endpoints version 2 with iOS.

The only documentation is the legacy documentation at the following link [click here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/calling-from-ios)

Does anyone know where I can find such a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

There are docs on [the new client](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest), which are mentioned in the migration guides.

Comment: Thanks Saiyr, is there anything that is a bit more user friendly? As I find that document is more confusing. I may well be out of my depth here but for example where it says 'To add the framework to an Xcode project, drag GTLR.framework to the project's Linked Frameworks source group, then add the GTLR framework from the Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries phases inside of the application target.' Where do I drag GTLR.framework from?

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug on the repository if you find the docs to be unhelpful. I have no iOS expertise, so I can't personally help you.